# Background sky is gridded

Tags: modeling, rendering

[[image: 1]
So I've been working on this haunted house for a school project and I got a problem.  Whenever I zoom out, the grid would come towards me and block the model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely have *Transparent* checked under the film section of the render properties panel. Uncheck it to bring back the background:

[image: Transparent]